# Random iteration over a dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, csv, random, iteration

I'm trying to randomly iterate over a Dataframe. The file I'm reading from is a CSV file:

pyquiz.csv

```
variables,statements,True or False
f1, f_state1, F
f2, true_state1,T
f3, f_state2, F
f20, f_state20, F
```

Dataframe

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'variables': ['f1', 'f2', 'f3', 'f20'],
    'statements': ['f_state1', 'true_state1', 'f_state2', 'f_state20'],
    'True of False': ['F', 'T', 'F', 'F']
})
```

After I randomly iterate over the file, I want set a condition based on the third column.

Below is code that I wrote previously that I want to try to accomplish something similar using Pandas but with a CSV file instead of a list:

```
if user_input == 'pyquiz':
for value in sorted(quiz_list, key=lambda _: random.random()):
    print(value)

    x = input("Enter T or F: ")

    if value in true_statements and x == 'T':
        print("Correct!")
        y = input('\nPress enter to continue: ')

    if value in true_statements and x == 'F':
        print("Incorrect.")

    if value in false_statements and x == 'F':
        print("Correct!")
        y = input("\nPress enter to continue:\n ")

    if value in false_statements and x == 'T':
        print("Incorrect.")
```

Comment: Shuffle the row index or just the integer positions of the dataframe's rows and use the shuffled list to access rows in a random order.

Comment: What do you mean by "randomly iterate"? Do you want to see each row once, in a random order? Do you want to see randomly chosen rows (possibly duplicated) a specific number of times? Something else? Does it matter if the DataFrame is changed (for example, by re-ordering the rows)?

Comment: Hi, Karl. I meant each row in a random order, specifically I want to see the statements in a random order. It doesn't matter if the order of the dataframe is changed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try:

```py
from random import shuffle

idx = df.index.to_list()  # get index to a list
shuffle(idx)              # shuffle the list using `random.shuffle()`

for i in idx:             # iterate over the shuffled list
    print(df.iloc[i])     # access the index using `.iloc`
```

Prints (for example):

```
variables                 f2
statements       true_state1
True or False              T
Name: 1, dtype: object

variables              f1
statements       f_state1
True or False           F
Name: 0, dtype: object

variables              f3
statements       f_state2
True or False           F
Name: 2, dtype: object

variables              f20
statements       f_state20
True or False            F
Name: 3, dtype: object
```

---

Dataframe used:

```
  variables   statements True or False
0        f1     f_state1             F
1        f2  true_state1             T
2        f3     f_state2             F
3       f20    f_state20             F
```